# In Visual Studio, what's the common structure for 3rd party files outside of c++ project director such as glad.h and glfw3.lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I was following the tutorial of learning OpenGL [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window), and got "glad/glad.h no such file or directory" error. My structure of 3rd party files:

```
C:\Deleveper\Libs (directory)
--glfw3.lib
--glad (directory)
----glad.h
--KHR (directory)
----khrplatform.h
```

In the project property setting, I have added "C:\Deleveper\Libs" into "Include Directories". In the linker tab I've also added "glfw3.lib" and "opengl32.lib".

====update====

Two things I did wrong:

1. I should separate .h and .lib files into two directories, usually "include" and "lib".
2. I should add both directories into "Include Directories" and "Library Directories" accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common structure of libraries has three important folders: include, lib, and bin. Include will have the headers, lib will contain the library files you link to your program at compile time, and bin contains the dll file that go in the same directory as your exe. Moving your dll file to the right directory can be done manually, though I'm sure there is an automatic solution. The header directories you put in additional include directories, and library directories go in additional library directories.

[image: Headers]
[image: Libraries]

The fact that they are only directories is important. To specify the header, you do that when #include-ing in your code. For specifying libraries, you do that in the additional dependencies.

[image: Include]
[image: Libs]