# How do I get OpenGL to work with Visual Studio Code on Windows?

Tags: c++, json, opengl, visual-studio-code, glfw

I wanted to move over to VS Code so I started by literally moving all of the necessary files and directories over to a folder that I opened in VS Code. I then proceeded to create an "include" folder and a "lib" folder:

[image: here is an image of the folder]

I then used some of my previous knowledge on setting up VS Code to try creating the "tasks.json", "launch.json" and the cpp_propertiesfile. This is where I have gotten stuck. From my knowledge;

- the cpp_properties file configures the intellisense..?
- the launch.json contains the debugging configurations..?
- the tasks.json is used to smush all the files together into a .exe..?

What's weird is that I tried this command

```
g++ -I./include -L./lib F:\opengl\src\stb_image.cpp F:\opengl\src\main.cpp F:\opengl\src\glad.c F:\opengl\glfw3.dll -o openGL.exe
```

and it popped out a .exe which ran the program fine. I tried putting some of these parameters in tasks.json, launch.json (pretty much everywhere) and I kept on receiving errors.

**c_cpp_properties:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",
                "-lglfw3.dll",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know how each of these files actually works since I have no clue whatsoever. I also want to know how I should go about setting up an OpenGL project from scratch on VS Code windows.

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING. "Windows" is not an acronym, and you don't need to scream it.

Comment: Not sure there's a question here. There's likely no "tutorials" for Visual Studio Code, but there is examples and documentation to work from.

Comment: Another thing: If you're looking to learn graphics programming it's probably better to pick up Vulcan than OpenGL, as Vulcan is likely to be the dominant force going forward. OpenGL is still useful, but more in its OpenGL ES form as use by things like WebGL.

Comment: Avoid text that is not relevant to the question. The second and third paragraph are completely irrelevant for the question.

Comment: I have an answer to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66113162/6815381. You set up you're header files to be included and link your library files, then you put your dll files in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Very unlikely that an OpenGL program uses a single source file , so use a build tool like `Make` or `CMake`

Comment: The question is too broad, asking too many separate questions.  You mention "I kept on receiving errors".  I suggest focusing on that part: what exactly did you do, and what error did you receive?  Even better, can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact same problem before, and this kind of programming isn't as fun as actual programming, so I'm going to just give you what I did that worked for me:

[image]

And this is the makefile, with the usages of include `INCLUDES = -Iinclude`, libraries `-Llib -lglfw3...`, and source code are all the rest

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGSSHORT = -std=c++17 -O3 -g
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic  -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-copy $(CXXFLAGSSHORT)
LDFLAGS = -Llib -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lglew32s -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreetype -lpsapi -lstdc++fs -lOpenAL32
INCLUDES = -Iinclude

SRC = $(wildcard src/core/private/*.cpp)  $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/blocks/private/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/models/*.cpp)
LIBSRC = $(wildcard src/profiler/*.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
LIBOBJ = $(LIBSRC:.cpp=.o)
EXEC = World_of_Engineering.exe
UTIL_EXEC = projectUtils.exe

all: $(EXEC)

include/noise/FastNoise.o: include/noise/FastNoise.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGSSHORT) $(INCLUDES) -c $^ -o $@

$(LIBOBJ): $(LIBSRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGSSHORT) $(INCLUDES) -c $^ 

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(EXEC): $(OBJ) $(LIBOBJ) include/noise/FastNoise.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LBLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) $(EXEC) build

.PHONY: all clean
```

As you can see I didn't bother to move .o files to a build folder, but it's usable

As far as all the .vscode files go, I don't need to touch any of them as they are autogenerated, with the exception of adding a configuration and changing the executable path:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
...
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/program.exe",
...
```

But this is only if you want debugging, you can just run the exe as is after compiling linking.